# Are listed in Where are specifications for 「constructor.prototype」

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

```
function Js() {};
var js = new Js();
js.constructor.prototype; //Js {}
Js.prototype = {};
js.constructor.prototype; Object {}
```

---

```
function Js() {};
var js = new Js();
js.constructor;//function Js() {}
Js.prototype = {};
js.constructor;//function Js() {}
```

---

The difference between `constructor.prototype` and `constructor`?

Have been described in where behavior specification of about `constructor.prototype`?

Comment: `js.constructor === Js`, hence `js.constructor.prototype === Js.prototype`. `Js` is a function and `Js.prototype` is an object. Not sure what your question really is. You can read about `prototype` in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.2) if that's what you want.

Comment: Have been described in where?

Comment: If you are asking where `prototype` is described, follow the link in my comment. Here it is again: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.2

Comment: Answer Thank you. I wanted to know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `constructor` object only reference the function which made the object, while the `prototype` contain all the properties and methods that will be inherited form a object, including the `constructor` property itself.